# Laravel validation - ErrorException in helpers.php line 466: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: validation, laravel

So, I followed the laravel documentation to create a validator. But every time the validation fails, I get a nasty "ErrorException in helpers.php line 466".
If I dump the $validator before the redirect, everything seems to be perfect and all the errors are there. But, after the redirect, I get the problem.

routes.php

```
Route::group(['as' => 'todas'], function(){
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'as' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'Web'], function(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'dashboard', 'as' => 'privadas', 'namespace' => 'Privadas'], function(){
      Route::get('criar', ['uses' => 'PrivateController@criar', 'as' => 'criar']);
      Route::post('salvar', ['uses' => 'FestaController@salvar', 'as' => 'salvar']);
    });
  });
});
```

kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

The controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web\Privadas;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Validator;

class FestaController extends Controller
{
    public function salvar(Request $request){
      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'numConvidados' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        'inicioFesta'   => 'required|date|before:' . $request->fimFesta,
        'fimFesta'      => 'required|date|after:' . $request->inicioFesta . '|mais_x_dias:' . $request->inicioFesta . ',1'
      ]);
      if ($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('dashboard/criar')
          ->withErrors($validator)
          ->withInput();
      }
      dd('success');
    }
}
```

The part of the view which contains the $errors variable

```
@section('subHeader')
@if (count($errors) > 0) {{-- Div de erros --}}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{$errors}}
    <strong>{{ trans('mensagens.opa-algo-deu-errado')}}</strong>
    <br>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endif
@endsection
```

The error is called:
ErrorException in helpers.php line 466:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: E:[....]\resources\views\privadas\criar-evento.blade.php)

```
in helpers.php line 466
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('E:\Profissional\photo2me\Repos\photo2me\storage\framework\views/07ef3b6137fe5cd5f04a28b6acfeb98af95e1888.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('E:\Profissional\photo2me\Repos\photo2me\resources\views/privadas/criar-evento.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 142
at View->getContents() in View.php line 113
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 82
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 197
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1030
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(PrivateController), object(Route), object(Request), 'criar') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Web\Privadas\PrivateController', 'criar') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 28
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 705
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 678
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `{{$errors}}`in blade file

Comment: Fu**. That was my bad... I added that {{$errors}} for a debbug I did earlier and I forgot to remove it. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for the highlight @paranoid!

Comment: I'll accept your answer, I just have to wait 7 minutes. Thanks again! :)